# Google Map Crash only in Android 7 after August, 2023

Tags: android, google-maps, crash, google-maps-markers

We are having the crash below without changing any code after the 10th of August, 2023.
It suddenly came out from all our app production versions from our Firebase Crashlytics report.

Suspected the API of Google Maps has been changed.
Does anyone have the same issue or know the workaround?

[image: 100% Android 7]

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6937)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:1118)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:5205)
       at android.view.View.invalidateInternal(View.java:13686)
       at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:13650)
       at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:13634)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.lite.s.l(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@231710108@231710104031.542928491.542928491)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.lite.n.d(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@231710108@231710104031.542928491.542928491:2)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.ei.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@231710108@231710104031.542928491.542928491:3)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: We do experience exactly the same recently even thouth the log is talking about updating the wrong thread. 
Can't figure out whats happening here

Comment: Same here, no idea where it's coming from

Comment: And it's impossible to replicate using an emulator, this is frustrating

Comment: Yeah, impossible to reproduce it in emulators. We had to use real devices and update Google Play Service to debug the issue.